# Alteration of stored procedure containing loop is taking too long

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I didn't find any appropriate solution for my problem so I want to ask here if someone could help me.

I have a stored procedure named `spImportWord` which downloads word files from a file location on another server to a local folder and saves values from each word file to a table in the database. For each file I'm calling a console application that saves the files to the local folder. For downloading I'm using a `while` loop. Before I used a `cursor` but as far as I know you should stay away from `cursors`.

Since I changed from `cursor` to `while` I can't even *alter* my stored procedure. It takes an eternity to finish. Is there any way to improve my stored procedure? (Note: With the `cursor` the SP could be altered but execution displayed that the subquery returned more than 1 value etc.)

My code so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spImportWord
@fileId INT
AS
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @filename VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @foldername VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @remotePath VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @localPath VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @organisationId INT
DECLARE @folderId INT
DECLARE @import TABLE(ImportId INT)
DECLARE @counter INT

SELECT @filename = Files.FileName
    , @foldername = Files.FolderName
FROM Files WHERE Files.FileId = @fileId

CREATE TABLE #organisation ([OrganisationId] INT, [FolderId] INT, [Year] VARCHAR(4) NULL)
INSERT INTO #organisation
SELECT [tabInstitution].[OrganisationId]
    , [tabInstitution].[FolderId]
    , [tabInstitution].[UploadDate] AS [Year]
FROM [tabInstitution]

SET @organisationId = 0
SET @counter = 0
WHILE (@counter <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #organisation))
BEGIN
    SELECT @organisationId = MIN([#organisation].[OrganisationId])
        , @folderId = [#organisation].[FolderId]
        , @year = [#organisation].[Year]
    FROM [#organisation]
    WHERE [#organisation].[OrganisationId] > @organisationId
    GROUP BY [FolderId], [Year]
    SET @remotePath = '\\somepath.path.com\somefolder\' + @organisationId + '\' + @folderId + '\' + @filename + '.docx'
    SET @localPath = 'C:\Files\' + @year + '\' + @foldername + '\' + @organisationId + '.docx'

    SET @cmd = 'C:\App\ImportWordFiles.exe --SourcePath ' + @remotePath + ' --TargetPath ' + @localPath
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output

    -- Log into database
    INSERT INTO WordImport
    OUTPUT Inserted.ImportId INTO @import
    VALUES(GETDATE())

    INSERT INTO WordImportItem
    VALUES((SELECT ImportId FROM @import), @organisationId, @folderId, @localPath)

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Instead of the `while` loop I had before:

```
DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
SELECT [#organisation].[OrganisationId]
    , [#organisation].[FolderId]
    , [#organisation].[Year]
FROM [#organisation]
OPEN MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @organisationId, @folderId, @year
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    [...]
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @organisationId, @folderId, @year
END
```

I hope I explained my question understandable.

Comment: What if you drop and re-create the stored procedure?

Comment: When I dropped it, the recreation also took ages. So I decided to close the SQL Server Studio and reopen it. Now the recreation worked.

Comment: Sounds like that instance of SSMS was using too many resources and just needed to be closed and reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know, you should really understand the reasons why cursors are considered bad. In your case, there's no reason *not* to use cursors, and in fact, your `while` solution is much uglier anyway.

As for your "subquery problem", `(SELECT ImportId FROM @import)` is to blame - you're continuously adding rows to `@import`, and the subquery returns all the `ImportId`s, not just the last one (or whatever). That will fail once `@import` has more than a single row. It's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to do - I assume you're just trying to get the last inserted ID, and there's no point in maintaining a whole table of all the import IDs. Just delete all the data from `@import` after you read it.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Should've noticed it.